Best Practices for Type-Safe Route Management in React Navigation for Conditional Authentication Flows
I'm developing a React Native app using React Navigation and facing a challenge with managing type-safe navigation for a dynamic authentication flow. The app allows users to access certain screens without being logged in. However, for specific actions like making a purchase, starting a chat, or booking a place, the user is redirected to a login/signup flow if not authenticated.
    Home -> ProductItemScreen -> PurchaseScreen -- (If not logged in, redirect to) --> 
    Registration/Login -> OTP Screen

After completing the OTP verification, I want the user to return to the original screen where they initiated the action (e.g., PurchaseScreen, Chat, Booking). This return should not be hardcoded as the initiation point can vary.
My navigation Structure looks like this
const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
const PrimaryStack = createStackNavigator<PrimaryStackParamList >();

export const PrimaryStackScreen: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Primary.Navigator>
      <Primary.Group>
        <Primary.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
        <Primary.Screen name="Places" component={Places} />
        <Primary.Screen name="ProdcutItems" name={ProdcutItems} />
        <Primary.Group />

        <Primary.Group>
          <Primary.Screen name="Bookings" name={Bookings} />
          <Primary.Screen ="Registration" name={Registration}/>
          <Primary.Screen ="Login" name={Login}/>
          <Primary.Screen ="OTP" name={OTP}/>
        <Primary.Group>
    </Primary.Navigator>
  );
};

export const RootStackScreen: React.FC = () => {
  return (
          <RootStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          >
            <RootStack.Screen name="Primary" component={PrimayStackScreen} />
          </RootStack.Navigator>
    );
};

One example I'm facing involves a scenario where the authentication flow is triggered and the user has navigated to the OTP screen, which is typically 3-4 screens beyond where the auth flow started. Once the user completes the authentication process, I want to redirect them back to their initial starting point. For instance, if the user initiated the auth flow from the 'ProductsItems' screen, they should be returned to that screen upon successful authentication. Even though I can access the routing state using navigate.getState(), I can't use it as a parameter because of a type mismatch; the use navigation hook expects a specific type, which I have globally defined according to the docs
declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}

There are several examples in the documentation and other sources about how to handle the authentication flow. However, the problem with most of these approaches is that they begin at the login screen and, once authenticated, remove those screens from the stack.
